# Prolog: Read list of sublists from file while keeping elements of each sublist as their original type

Tags: prolog

So i have a program which saves a large list of sublists to a file. Each sublist has an ID, Name and grade. ID and name are stored as single quoted strings. example (quotes get removed when i save the file and the underlying list is stored as something like:

```
 [ [005,Chester,100], [001,Bob,99], [002,Andy,77] ... ]
```

My function to save this to a file looks like (X is the list of sublists):

```
% ----- OPTION 2, STORE TO FILE
process(2, X) :-
  open('hogwarts.txt',write,Stream),
  write(Stream,X), write(Stream, '.'),
  close(Stream),
  nl, nl, menu(X).
```

My function to load the saved file looks like:

```
% ----- OPTION 1, LOAD FROM FILE
process(1, X) :-
  open('hogwarts.txt',read,Str),
  read(Str,TOHERE),
  close(Str),
  write(TOHERE), nl, menu(TOHERE).
```

when i write(TOHERE) after loading the saved file i get stuff like:

```
[[2, _G316, 67], [1, _G328, 100]]
```

is it possible to keep the elements of the sublist as their proper types after loading the list from a saved file? (keep ID & Name fields as single quoted strings and grade as a number)
thanks.

Comment: They're *predicates* in Prolog that define relations. Not *functions* that process inputs and outputs. :) What's the role of `X` in `process(1, X)`? Also, in your original list,`Chester` and `Bob` are variables, not atoms or strings. They need to be in single quotes.

Comment: @lurker X is the list of sublists. there's another function in my program that allows the user to enter ID and Name as single quoted strings and then grade as a number and stores all the sublists inside X, but when i store that list to a txt file that's what it looks like (single quotes removed)

Comment: You mean there's another *predicate*. ;) Your predicate which stores the txt file needs to retain the quotes.

Comment: @lurker predicate yes haha. is that even possible with the way my list is constructed? because when i write to file all the quotes get removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `writeq` in your predicate:

```
process(2, X) :-
  open('hogwarts.txt',write,Stream),
  writeq(Stream,X), write(Stream, '.'),
  close(Stream),
  nl, nl, menu(X).
```

This will maintain the quoting in your atoms, which you require.

Comment: haha why is it always so easy? i was reading all night and i swear i never saw "writeq" anywhere. guess sleep deprivation will cause you to overlook things. THANKS AGAIN!!

Comment: @GeorgeCostanza yes, the online SWI documentation is reference, not a how-to. So you have to know what you're looking for to find it. It's generally not easy.

Answer (score 2):

Can you edit the file?

Then I would suggest: `'Chester'` and `'Bob'`. If you put them into `'` then they are terms. Otherwise they are free variables.

Comment: there's another function in my program that allows the user to enter ID and Name as single quoted strings and then grade as a number and stores all the sublists inside X, but when i store that list to a txt file that's what it looks like (single quotes removed). i guess this is what causes the issue when i then try to load the txt file back into the program